# Pymongo ignoring my limit parameter

Tags: mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

I am using Pymongo (v3.5.1) in a Python v3.6.3 Jupyter notebook.

### Problem

Even-though I am limiting my results, the db.collection.find() is still retrieving all results before returning

My code:

```
for post in posts.find({'subreddit_1':"the_donald"}, limit=2):
    print(post)
    exit
```

[image: Output from the command db.currentOp()]

### Background

I have imported the Reddit comment data set (RC_2017-01) from [files.pushshift.io](http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/) and created an index on the subreddit field (subreddit_1).

[image: My collection's format]

## My Indexes

[image]

Comment: `for post in posts.find({'subreddit_1':"the_donald"}).limit(2):` also causes the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by the collection having no index on your query term, as exhibited by the line:

```
planSummary: COLLSCAN
```

which means that to answer your query, MongoDB is forced to look at each document in the collection one by one.

Creating an index to support your query should help. You can create an index in the `mongo` shell by executing:

```
db.posts.createIndex({'subreddit_1': 1})
```

This is assuming your collection is named `posts`.

Please note that creating that index would only help with the query you posted. It's likely that different index would be needed for different type of queries.

To read more about how indexing works in MongoDB, check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: Thank you for your help. subreddit_1 is the index. subreddit is the unindexed attribute. You might still be right however. I'll update my post with screenshots of the indexes. I think the index might have not been created correctly.

Comment: @GabrielFair then the query is wrong, since you specified `db.posts.find({subreddit_1:'the_donald'})`, which means that you wanted documents where the field `subreddit_1` contains the value `the_donald`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the query, because in find() method 2nd parameter is projection. Find() always return cursor and limit function always works on cursor.

So the syntax should like below:

```
for post in posts.find({'subreddit_1':"the_donald"})[<start_index>:<end_index>]
print(post)
exit
```

OR

```
    for post in posts.find({'subreddit_1':"the_donald"}).limit(2)
print(post)
exit
```

Please read the [doc](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) for detail

Comment: Thank you for your help. Interestingly the docs say that the parameters are optional and specified by name binding. So the order doesn't matter. Also in my comment above I mentioned how I get the same results if `.limit(2)` is appended to the function. I will make that more clear in my post now. cheers.